# fscanf issue with reading in key-value pairs

Tags: c, scanf

EDIT:Since it was asked, I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and it has raised no warnings.

I'm somewhat new to C, and file i/o has always been an issue for me. How would I go about parsing key value pairs in the form of "keyName: valueName"? My issue comes into play because my values could be a string, a float, or an unsigned int.

I'm writing a game using SDL2 and I'm trying to keep as much of the config for individual actors in separate .actor files. Following some sample code I've managed to read the key portion of the pair via fscanf, however when I attempt to fscanf the value in to my actor I get an exception.

Player.actor

```
folder: images/Player/
scale: 1.0,1.0
color: 255,255,255,255
colorSpecial: 10,255,100,255
xOffset: 1
numAnimations: 3

name: idle
filename: playerIdle.png
length: 8
frameWidth: 39
frameHeight: 87
frameRate: 0.75
type: loop

name: attack
filename: playerPunch.png
length: 8
frameWidth: 50
frameHeight: 82
frameRate: 0.75
type: once

name: walk
filename: playerWalk.png
length: 7
frameWidth: 50
frameHeight: 82
frameRate: 0.85
type: loop
```

Code:

```
void LoadActor(Actor *actor, char *filename)
{
  FILE * file;
  char buf[512];
  char* imageFile = "";
  int i = 0;

  file = fopen(filename, "r");

  if (!file)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  rewind(file); 

  while (fscanf(file, "%s", buf) != EOF) //this works
  {
    if (strcmp(buf, "numAnimations:") == 0) // this works
    {
        fscanf(file, "%i", i); // this doesn't?

        continue;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%i", &i);` You need to pass the address.

Comment: You should be getting a warning for that.  What is your compiler?

Comment: the `rewind(file); ` is useless, you just open the file

Comment: why the `continue` in the `while` ? you do not need it to loop ^^

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and I didn't notice I still had that continue there.

Comment: And the compiler says nothing about the _fscanf(file, "%i", i)_ ?

Comment: As a side note, you'd probably be better off using a ready-made config file parser library rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @bruno, no not at all

Comment: @IanAbbott I will have to look into that, since I've been at this for over a day now

Comment: incredible. Look at the options to ask for more warning, lot of compiler have that kind of options (for instance _gcc_ has for instance `-pedantic -Wextra`)

Comment: You need to increase the default warning level of your compiler.

Comment: My MSVC also warns: *warning C4098: 'LoadActor': 'void' function returning a value.* And why doesn't the function `LoadActor` use its argument `Actor *actor`?

Comment: With VS, that should be under `project properties → C/C++ → General → Warning Level`. Set that to "EnableAllWarnings (/Wall)". But I just tried it and still did not get a warning.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think I fixed that, it was because of return NULL?

Comment: That's right, `void` function returned `NULL`.

Comment: I have now enabled all warnings, so I shall get back to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I attempt to fscanf the value in to my actor I get an exception.
>
> ```
>        fscanf(file, "%i", i); // this doesn't?
> ```

`fscanf(file, "%i", &i);` You need to pass the address.
                    – Johnny Mopp